# Close Swipeable functional component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `Flatlist` rendered with the following `ListItemSwipeable` and they hold as `renderRightActions` the `RightActionsButton` function. Swiping works and the button appears. However, I can not achieve that the button disappears when another element is swiped or the button is pressed.

```
const RightActionsButton = ({ progress, dragX, onPress }) => {
    const scale = dragX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-100, 0],
      outputRange: [1, 0],
      extrapolate: "clamp"
    });
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <View>
          <Animated.Text style={{ transform: [{ scale }] }}>
            Button!
          </Animated.Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

 const ListItemSwipeable = ({data, onAction}) => {
        return (
            <Swipeable
            renderRightActions={(progress, dragX) => (
                <RightActionsButton progress={progress} dragX={dragX} onPress={onAction} />
              )}
            >
            <View>
                <Text>{data}</Text>
            </View>
          </Swipeable>
        )
    }
    };
```

There are some hints [here](https://github.com/jshanson7/react-native-swipeable/blob/master/example/swipeable-example.js), however it is class based and I would need it for function based component.